# How to add days to a POSIXct object in R

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

I would like to add specific days to POSIXct object. I tried the below method

```
library(lubridate)
input_time = as.POSIXct("2018-05-05T14:14:05")
input_time +  lubridate::days(1)
```

This gives the output as "2018-05-06 UTC" without the hours and seconds (14:14:05). I would like to have it in the same format as input_time (2018-05-06T14:14:05). How to retain the hours and seconds information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your time format is not being tested by `as.POSIXct`. This is why you get this result.

You can use the following format to get it correct:

```
library(lubridate)

# note the format option to get it correct
input_time = as.POSIXct("2018-05-05T14:14:05", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
input_time + lubridate::days(1)

[1] "2018-05-06 14:14:05 UTC"
```

or just use everything with functions from lubridate:

```
input_time <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2018-05-05T14:14:05")
input_time + lubridate::days(1)

[1] "2018-05-06 14:14:05 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just format correctly and add the seconds of a day.

```
as.POSIXct("2018-05-05T14:14:05", format="%Y-%m-%dT%T") + 1*60*60*24
# [1] "2018-05-06 14:14:05 CEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use as.POSIXlt instead of as.POSIXct.
POSIXlt stores data/time as a list of element:

```
new_date<-input_time
new_date$mday<-input_time$mday+1
new_date
```

formatting input_time as below and adding the timezone (for example, GMT):

```
input_time = as.POSIXlt("2018-05-05T14:14:05", format='%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S', tz="GMT")
```