# How to compute a date according to a column with number of days?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Consider the dataset with the following format:

| StartDate | NbOfDays | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-23 08:00:00 | 65 | NA |
| 2019-10-08 08:00:00 | 30 | 2019-11-08 08:00:00 |

How to compute the `EndDate` when it is a missing value, according to the `NbOfDays` variable?

#### Expected output

| StartDate | NbOfDays | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-23 08:00:00 | 65 | 2018-11-28 08:00:00 |
| 2019-10-08 08:00:00 | 30 | 2019-11-08 08:00:00 |

Comment: use `lubridate`. convert both columns to appropriate types, then use `df$StartDate + days(df$NbOfDays)` to get enddate

Comment: could you be more precise with "massive" data set? 1000s of rows, millions, 100s of millions?

Comment: See also: [How to add days to a POSIXct object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64482049/10488504)

Comment: @MichaelChirico More than 4 millions rows !

Comment: some advice (1) of you're getting the data from csv, data.table::fread might be able to give you POSIXct for start/end columns directly (for conversion within R, use the fasttime package) (2) check how many unique rows there are -- if there are a lot of duplicates, you can run the addition just one time for each unique combination

Comment: @MichaelChirico Hi, it wasn't a CSV nor an excel file in fact, but i applied the solution of @/imdevskp and it worked perfectly ! But thanks for your suggestion anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df
            StartDate NbOfDays             EndDate
1 2018-09-23 08:00:00       65 2018-11-28 08:00:00
2 2019-10-08 08:00:00       30 2018-11-28 08:00:00

df %>% 

  mutate(StartDate = ymd_hms(StartDate)) %>%
  mutate(EndDate = StartDate + days(NbOfDays))

            StartDate NbOfDays             EndDate
1 2018-09-23 08:00:00       65 2018-11-27 08:00:00
2 2019-10-08 08:00:00       30 2019-11-07 08:00:00
```

Comment: I didn't saw your edit before saying that i had weird results, let's try with this new one, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can add the days by multiplying with 24 hours 60 minutes and 60 Seconds.

```
as.POSIXct("2018-09-23 08:00:00", "UTC") + 65 * 24*60*60
#[1] "2018-11-27 08:00:00 UTC"
```

It looks like you have to add 1 day to come to your desired result.